# On Borel-measurable discontinuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $g$ is $1$-periodic (i.e. $g(x+1)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$) and for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and any $c,d\in[0,1]$ with $c<d$ the set $\{x\in[a,b]: g(x)\in[c,d]\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

**Question 1:** Does a function $g$ as described above even exist?

**Question 2:** If the answer to Question 1 is `yes', then is it true that for almost every $\beta\in[0,1]$ the function $f_\beta:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$ given by $f_\beta(x):=g(x+\beta)-g(x)$ is not continuous?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does $g = (\sin(2\pi x)+1)/2$ not work for Part 1?

Comment: I believe that [Conway's base thirteen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) (slightly modified to be 1-periodic and have range $[0, 1]$) gives an example for 1, but my memory may be off.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Not at all - the $g$ you describe is continuous, and no $g$ satisfying (1) can be continuous. Note that any such $g$ has to have $g([a, b])=[0, 1]$ for every $a<b$; in particular, no such function can be continuous anywhere.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks. I didn't read the quantifiers carefully enough.